# What does MMS Alert "Host is exposed to the public Internet" mean?

Tags: mongodb

I started receiving MongoDB Management Service emails today saying this: "Host is exposed to the public Internet". Apparently these checks are run on the 1st and 15th of the month, and today is the 1st. I looked [here](http://mms.mongodb.com/help-classic/faq/#my-alert-email-says-my-host-s-are-exposed-to-the-public-internet-what-does-that-mean) for more information but it didn't really help me.

I have my personal website running at [andrewkoroluk.com](http://andrewkoroluk.com/). I am running an Express NodeJS server there, hooked up to port 80. In it, I use a MongoDB database for various data such as authentication, website data, files, etc. I have `mongod` always running. I am making an API that manipulates the data in my MongoDB database, but I doubt that that is what triggered these alerts.

Should I be worried about these alerts?

Comment: I don't suppose the fact that your web server is currently down could be related?

Comment: No, I'm in the middle of an update ;)

Comment: to be fair, your question should probably asked to the people providing the service and running the check rather than us, but I can't seem to reach the standard ports usually used by mongodb from my end. I would try connecting from the internet to your mongodb instance if it uses a non-standard port, and seeing if in fact your instance is accessible to the public internet.

Comment: How would I go about testing that? Just pinging the mongo port? (it uses the standard port) Or could I try running something like mongo-express locally and have it try to connect to my server?

Comment: You would confirm the port mongodb is currently using by checking its configuration, or using the `netstat` command as per usual. You would then use `telnet` to test the TCP connection. At this point we're getting quite closer to questions for Superuser though.

Comment: Yo, why the sudden downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple: **Your MongoDB server is potentially accessible from the public internet.**

A quick check showed that it's none of your hosts with a DNS entry.

Please make sure that the MongoDB port isn't accessible from the public internet by using a firewall and/or binding MongoDB to a private IP. Furthermore, you should use [keyfiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/generate-key-file/) and [user authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/).